# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException occured. but I didn't change anything

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException occured While I'm developing using Spring boot.

In to the point, I didn't change anything.

I tried check the fileUtil class, but there isn't any specific problem.
And did "Project clean" and reboot eclipse.

after searched on google, somebody says "check your annotation is valid"
so I checked annotations but there is nothing to guess

but error still not solved..
I'll show you my code

this is the exception.

```
심각: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'config': No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties] found for dependency [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties] found for dependency [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties] found for dependency [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
```

This is the stackTrace that I got from application after add @Component annotation.

```
심각: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'config': No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties] found for dependency [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties] found for dependency [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties] found for dependency [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
```

and this is [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]

```
(@Component <<- I added this annotation but nothing change )
public class ConfigProperties {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigProperties.class);

    private Properties properties;

    public ConfigProperties() {
        LOG.info("ConfigProperties");
    }

    // ~ Implementation Method. ~~~~~~~~
    // ~ Self Methods. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    public final void init() {
        // 환경 변수 설정 log 출력
        if (this.properties != null) {
            LOG.info("Initialize Config Variables");
//            LOG.info(JsonUtil.marshallingJsonWithPretty(this.properties));
        }
    }

    // ~ Getter and Setter
    // ==============================================================================================


    public final void setProperties(final Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public final String getString(final String key) {

        return this.properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    public final Integer getInteger(final String key) {
        String value = this.properties.getProperty(key);
        return new Integer(value);
    }

}
```

This is fileUtil

```
/**
 * 업로드 파일 유틸
 */
@Component("fileUtil")
public class FileUtil {

    /**
     * The constant LOG.
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUtil.class);

    /**
     * The Config.
     */
    @Autowired
    private ConfigProperties config;

    ......
}
```

This problem is I have never seen...

and my application had completely worked until 3 hours ago.
repeatly, I didn't change anything

waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> No qualifying bean of type [com.m2u.chatbotany.common.utils.ConfigProperties]

Above error is because in `FileUtil` you have autowired `ConfigProperties` but `ConfigProperties.class` is not annotated with `Stereotype (@Component, @Service etc)`

So add the @Component annotation like below

```java
@Component
public class ConfigProperties {

   // Code logic

}
```

Comment: even add annotation "@Component" you said. the error still occured

Comment: It should work, if u are running using jar delete that and try again (Do a clean build)

Comment: I tried delete and re-add libraries, and Do a project clean a lot. but It still not works.. I think I do the whole things I can